# Network Analyst Vehicle Routing - Point Barriers not diverting route

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, arccatalog

I'm using network analyst in ArcMap 10.3 to do a vehicle routing problem (I have all the extensions). I have a depot location and an order point. I can run the tool and it will run the route along the road from the depot to the order location. However, I am trying to add a point barrier to the road to simulate a road closure.

When I place the barrier on the road and click "solve" it runs the route along the road right through the barrier as if the barrier is not even there.

I know this is a hard question to answer without seeing my data, but does anyone have suggestions for me to start troubleshooting?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and include a screenshot?

Comment: I'd check the barrier type - there are barriers of restriction type and of add cost type. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/barriers.htm